# How to unload all the plugins from vim and change VIMRUNTIME?

Tags: ssh, vim, scp

I have an account at my hosting providers server and I can't install my own copy of vim.
So the only personalization I can make is editing .vimrc in my account, but it won't suffice

What I'd Like to do is:
on startup I'd like to unload all the plugins and loaded stuff, and tell vim to use other folder as its' runtime.

Any idea how to aproach it?

Answer (score 3):

You can start your vim with `-u NONE`. From the man-page:

```
       -u {vimrc}  Use the commands in the file {vimrc}  for  initializations.
               All  the  other  initializations  are skipped.  Use this to
               edit a special kind of files.  It can also be used to  skip
               all  initializations by giving the name "NONE".  See ":help
               initialization" within vim for more details.
```

For changing `$VIMRUNTIME` at runtime, use

```
:let $VIMRUNTIME = "/new/path/"
```

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question: you just need to set the `runtimepath` option in your `.vimrc` file, because your `.vimrc` is read before any plugins are loaded.

However, the default `runtimepath` value usually includes the `~/.vim` folder (use `:set runtimepath?` to check), so you should be able to add whatever plugins you need to the `~/.vim` folder. Also you can prevent many plugins from loading by adding a line such as `:let g:loaded_<plugin name> = 1` to your `.vimrc` file. Check the help docs for each plugin to find out how to do this.